# Using python/pandas, I need to remove all rows in an excel file that don't match a set of numbers with differing characters at the end

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I need to remove all of the rows that don't match "200001AAA" or "200001BBB" from the excel file.

I tried using `df.drop(df[df.NUMBER != '200001.'].index)` but it keeps returning with nothing. Any help is appreciated!

| Number | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200001AAA | XYZ | XYZ |
| 200001BBB | XYZ | XYZ |
| 200002AAA | XYZ | XYZ |
| 200002BBB | XYZ | XYZ |
| 200003AAA | XYZ | XYZ |
| 200003BBB | XYZ | XYZ |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the rows you want: Make a boolean Series and use that Series to [filter/index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) the rows you want.

Use [`.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) pattern matching: `200001` followed by either `AAA` or `BBB`.

```
mask = df['Number'].str.match('200001(AAA|BBB)')
df = df[mask]
```

Use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) with a list of acceptable values.

```
mask = df['Number'].isin(['200001AAA','200001BBB'])
df = df[mask]
```

Or maybe a simple as

```
mask = df['Number'].str.startswith('200001')
```